# What would never being unlucky do to a person?

Tags: internal-consistency, super-powers

Imagine the luckiest person on the planet. Everything that they do goes exactly their way without them asking it to happen. Wanting to check out at the supermarket? There's a cashier free. Approaching the traffic lights? They're always on green. Looking for a job? A nice and fitting job opening is found after only a few minutes of searching: they call back the same afternoon and schedule an interview for the next day and give you the job. You never need a bathroom break when not around one, your bus always shows up the moment you arrive at the stop, you never get the last cup of coffee from the pot so you have to make new at work and so on.

Note that this fortune does not go into the silly, so don't expect finding suitcases filled with thousands of dollars on the street or get invited to hang out with famous/rich people for helping them out with something minor. This person ain't no Gladstone Gander.

What would this never-ending supply of luck do to a person? Would it turn them into a self-centered jerk, someone who just cannot relate to other people or something else?

Comment: Read Larry Niven's books **Ringworld** and **Ringworld Engineers** for his take on the answer to your question.  The character in question is Teela Brown.

Comment: Read about Matt Cauthon in Robert Jordan's Wheel of Time.

Comment: Ask [Gladstone Gander](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gladstone_Gander)

Comment: Reminds of of an [X-Files episode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Goldberg_Variation_(The_X-Files)) centered around a guy who was extraordinarily lucky.  Unfortunately, there was a "balance" and his good luck meant that other people had bad luck.  And that had an effect on him.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The extraordinary amount of luck for this person could lead to an extraordinary lack of a fulfilling social life. If someone knew that they had a friend with such good luck, they would likely try to take advantage of this. The friend could ask them to win the lottery for them, and so gain a reputation for being used. Of course, they would be lucky enough to get out of this situation before it hurts someone, but it could ruin your reputation.

This reputation issue could lead to some rather limiting factors later as well. Imagine being banned from all luck-based events in their entirety because you have "too much luck". This could make the person in question very miserable.

Suppose they don't get involved in the life in which people take advantage of them. They wouldn't be able to understand the small problems people come across every day. They wouldn't ever be the one who can understand the feeling of, to use the examples provided, missing the bus as it pulls away from the stop or reaching the coffee pot to find it empty. When they create these events by being lucky enough to avoid them, they can end up frustraiting other people that they work with because of the habbits they pick up.

In the end, they would either end up alienated by society or alienating themselves through the actions they take because they are too lucky to see what they are missing.

Answer (score 2):

They would have a complete lack of empathy for the "human condition", never having experienced any of life's little (and not so little) frustrations. They might be able to appreciate others' problems from an academic point of view, but would never really understand. This could make them a very "cold" person, as seen through the eyes of their acquaintances- someone always on the edge of the crowd looking in. They might therefore, be somewhat lonely and that in turn, might make them bitter and angry that their "good fortune" has in fact worked against them.

Or would they be lucky that none of it worked against them and everyone loved them, against all the odds? :)